# how to use lxml find all the src tags and replace them

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I want to use lxml to got src content and replace them with space.
But the body still not be replaced
Please help me Thank you.

```
import re
import lxml.html
#the content of source.log is a webpage source code I got by scrapy
with open("source.log", "r") as bb:
    c_str = bb.read()
    body =  c_str.decode('utf-8')


doc  = lxml.html.fromstring(body)
src  = doc.xpath("//@src")

for ss in src:
    re.search(ss,body)
    body.replace(str(ss),'')
    print body
```

for example:
if the body is

```
'src="http://pic/1379181836.jpg"/><br>紅心<br></div><div>tel:12345678</div>' \
           'src="http://pic/4447918.jpg"/>'
```

the result I want would be:

```
'src=""/><br>紅心<br></div><div>tel:12345678</div>' \
           'src=""/>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, you need to assign the result of replace to the `body`:

```
for ss in src:
    body = body.replace(str(ss), '')
print body
```

---

Though, I personally don't like the approach. Better find *all tags that have `src` attribute* and set the attribute value to an empty string:

```
for element in doc.xpath("//*[@src]"):
    element.attrib['src'] = ''

print lxml.html.tostring(doc)
```

Comment: Thank you! your are right.And your code is very beautiful.